# How to send photo to server in android

Tags: android, phpmyadmin, android-imageview

I just had a confusion about the way a user can select the photo from file memory and set it as the profile photo and in the background, the photo should be sent to the server, Till now I have been able to give the user choose option and then set that photo in profile image but I still do not know what do I send over to the server, I don't know what API do i need and what is the right format to do so.
my current code is :

```
        playerImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent galleryintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
                              MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                   galleryintent.setType("image/*");
                   galleryintent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                   galleryintent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                   galleryintent.putExtra("scale", true);
                   galleryintent.putExtra("outputFormat",
                           Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

            startActivityForResult(galleryintent, i);
        }
    });

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == i && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        assert selectedImage != null;
        Log.i("selected Image",selectedImage.toString());
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),selectedImage);
            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
            Log.d("image",image);
            //passing the image to volley
            SendImage(image);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        saveImage(bitmap);
        playerImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
       // playerImage.setImageBitmap();
        pathToImage = selectedImage.getPath();
        //stuff to do on click button upload cover??
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

}

 public static void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    OutputStream output;
    String recentImageInCache;
    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    // Create a new folder in SD Card
    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
            + "/YOUR_APP/profile");
    dir.mkdirs();

    // Create a name for the saved image
    File file = new File(dir, username+".jpg");
    try {

        output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is where i do not have any clue

```
 private void SendImage( final String image) {
  final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(Matchboard.this, "updating in...", null, true, true);

    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url="http://www.judgement6.com/judgement_files/profileImage.php";
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("uploade",response);
                    try {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        Log.e("returns", String.valueOf(jsonObject));
                        if (jsonObject.toString().equals("image uploaded successfully")){
                           Toast.makeText(Matchboard.this,"image uploaded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
,
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(Matchboard.this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

        Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        params.put("image", image);
        params.put("email",userEmail);
        return params;
    }
};
{
    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

I also want to download that photo from the server everytime the user logs in so he/she does not have to set it everytime..
This is my profileImage.php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
require_once('connect.php');
$image=$_POST['image'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

$sql = "update users2 set profileImage='$image' where email='$email'";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
echo 'image uploaded successfully';
  } 
  else
    {
      echo 'oops! Please try again!';
    }   
   } 
  ?>
```

The all I want is to get image back in form of url like xyz.com/image/1.png type of thing

Comment: Could you provide formatted code? It will be easier to read. Thank you

Comment: well @Dumbo, the current code is the all I have written for doing that so tell me which part is not understandable to you or you can edit it

Comment: The first part of the question is trying to get the data from the file explorer by opening it and then setting it into the imageview whereas the second part is trying to send it to the remote server by using volley libraray

Comment: Use MultipartEntity for upload image on server, for more have look [this](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)

Comment: @HemantParmar I have my own server so I do not want to use coldfusion

Comment: So what is actually failing?

Comment: The column which is for saving the data which is coming from the app has some strange values it looks like the bitmap is saved to the server but I actually want to save the image in url format so i could retrieve it later with ease

Comment: I know its kind of weird but that's I hope you get what i want

Comment: Why do you need url? You can create another GET request.

Comment: Read this article https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/upload-image-to-server/

Comment: Ok let me see that